# Can we change button color of Swiper module in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I use React native.
I'd like to use Swiper from `react-native-swiper`.

**import Swiper from "react-native-swiper";**

Here as you can see, the button color is set `blue` as a **default** as well as `size`.

[image]

I use this `Swiper` as below.

```
<Swiper
  style={{
    width,
    height: 400,
  }}
  buttonWrapperStyle={{
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  }}
  horizontal
  showsButtons={true}
  showsPagination={true}
  }
>
  {file.map((onepic) => (
    <File
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={{ width, height: 400 }}
      source={{ uri: onepic }}
    ></File>
  ))}
</Swiper>
```

Even if I've searched a lot how to change button color and size, but nothing was found.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is props called `buttonWrapperStyle` which is nothing but a style.

You can even change style of specific left/right button by using `nextButton` or `prevButton` props

```
nextButton={()=><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>}
```

Find more in detail from here https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#control-buttons

Comment: I know that it has `buttonWrapperStyle` but from there, how can I change color of button? I can't insert `color: 'red'` and `backgroundColor` changes whole picture, not a button.

Comment: you can use `nextButton` and `prevButton` by providing it `<Text>` and customise it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
style={{'--swiper-navigation-color': 'blue'}}
```